# Can I create new page library in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss, page-library

As my current default page library has errors I want to create a new page library. However there are no such library in the list/library selection. I tried Document Library and Wiki Page Library which looks similar but they are not what I want. I want the Page Library with Publishing Features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are created by the Publishing Feature, you could try to Disable the Publishing Feature (Site Collection Features), Delete the Pages Library in SharePoint Designer (if that allows you) and Re-enable the feature so the Library is re-created.

This is very likely to explode tho, so do that in a restored backup.

But what errors are we talking here? If this library breaks IMO it is because of ContentTypes or Site Columns being misused, if you delete/recreate the Pages library you may not actually fix the problem.